ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Read access to project 'project-id' was denied]
I use Google Cloud Platform\Console for work.
In my work, I use Google Cloud Functions and the command gcloud functions deploy .
I didn't have a problem with this for a while ago, but today I ran into the following problem:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Read access to project 'project-id' was denied]

So, the steps that I follow are:

Authorization in the Google Cloud SDK Shell

Entering a command:
gcloud functions deploy cloud-function-name --gen2 --concurrency=1000 --memory=4G --timeout=3600 --source=. --entry-point=entry_point --region africa-south1 --runtime python312 --min-instances 0 --max-instances 5 --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml --service-account service-account-name.com --update-labels name=label-name


I get an error in response:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Read access to project 'project-id' was denied]



Here are the permissions and roles of the account under which I am logged into the Google Cloud SDK Shell:

Here are the roles and permissions that are provided for the Google Cloud Service Account passed in the parameter --service-account :

There are similar problems, the solution to which is to provide the Cloud Functions Developer role, but such a role already exists on two accounts.
Please help me, what is the problem and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Do you have multiple projects? If so, are you sure you're in the context of the right project? Try using the --project flag and see if you still get the error

Did you complete that additional configuration: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration  (you must also assign the user the Service Account User IAM role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the Cloud Functions runtime service account and Cloud Build service account.)

Do you have a "yellow" project ID in your Cloud Shell? If not, perform a "gcloud config set project " to set your project.

@NoCommandLine", I tried with the flag --project, but this didn't help:
D:\path>gcloud functions deploy function-name --project=project-id --gen2 --concurrency=1000 --memory=4G --timeout=3600 --source=. --entry-point=entry_point --region africa-south1 --runtime python312 --min-instances 0 --max-instances 100 --trigger-http --env-vars-file .env.yaml --service-account service-account --update-labels name=function-label  

But got same:
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Read access to project 'fresh-gravity-322709' was denied]

@guillaumeblaquiere, I don't have a "yellow" project ID in your Cloud Shell even after the command gcloud config set project <projectID>.
But i can update my existed functions using the same command and pass existed Google Cloud Function name.
But i can't deploauy a new function...
